# Naive Bayes on continuous variables

Tags: r, naive-bayes, bayes

Please allow me to ask a basic question. I understand the mechanics of Naive Bayes for discrete variables, and can redo the calculations "by hand". (code of HouseVotes84 all the way per below).

However - I am struggling to see how the mechanics work for continuous variables (example code per below). How does the package calculate the conditional probabilities `[, 1]` and `[, 2]` in the table per below? As any individual X value is unique, does it create a range around each point, and calculate relative frequencies within these ranges (e.g. if the point is +0.311, does it evaluate the incidence of blue and orange spots in e.g. a range of 0.1 and +0.5?) This might be basic question - apologies if so.

Table

```
A-priori probabilities:
Y
  blue orange 
   0.5    0.5 

Conditional probabilities:
        values
Y              [,1]      [,2]
  blue   0.08703793 0.9238799
  orange 1.33486433 0.9988389
```

Code

```
blue=rep("blue",50); orange=rep("orange",50); colour=c(blue,orange); values1=rnorm(50,0,1); values2=rnorm(50,1,1); values=c(values1,values2)
df=data.frame(colour,values)

(model <- naiveBayes(colour ~ ., data = df))
(predict(model, df[1:10,]))
(predict(model, df[1:10,], type = "raw"))
(pred <- predict(model, df))
table(pred, df$colour)

## Categorical data only:
library(e1071)
data(HouseVotes84, package = "mlbench")
HouseVotes84=HouseVotes84[,1:3]
(model <- naiveBayes(Class ~ ., data = HouseVotes84))
(predict(model, HouseVotes84[1:10,]))
(predict(model, HouseVotes84[1:10,], type = "raw"))
(pred <- predict(model, HouseVotes84))
table(pred, HouseVotes84$Class)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the R package (e1071) and the function naiveBayes that you're using:

The standard naive Bayes classifier (at least this implementation) assumes independence of the predictor variables, *and Gaussian distribution (given the target class) of metric predictors.* For attributes with missing values, the corresponding table entries are omitted for prediction.

It's pretty standard for continuous variables in a naive Bayes that a normal distribution is considered for these variables and a mean and standard deviation can then be calculated and then using some standard z-table calculations probabilities can be estimated for each of your continuous variables to make the naive Bayes classifier.  I thought that it was possible to change the distributional assumption in this package, but apparently I'm wrong.

There is another R package (klaR) where you can change the density kernel. (the function is NaiveBayes).  From the package:

```
NaiveBayes(x, grouping, prior, usekernel = FALSE, fL = 0, ...)
```

**usekernel**

*if TRUE a kernel density estimate (density) is used for denstity estimation. If FALSE a normal density is estimated.*

```
density(x, bw = "nrd0", adjust = 1,
        kernel = c("gaussian", "epanechnikov", "rectangular",
                   "triangular", "biweight",
                   "cosine", "optcosine")
```

Answer (score 0):

I was working on a project not that long ago for which I needed to compute a naive bayes classifier (from scratch). I started out in R, but once I had the process down, I moved the code to Python. Here's my code that I began with. Don't expect it to be polished. For the most part, I followed Wikipedia's example (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naive_Bayes_classifier#Examples).

The steps are simple:

1. calculate the a priori probabilities which are the proportion of classes
2. For your continuous data, assume a normal distribution and calculate the mean and standard deviation.
3. To classify observations, take the new input `x`, calculate `dnorm(x, mu, sigma)` where mu and sigma come from step 2.
4. Sum up log(apriori) + log(dnorm(...)).

At this point, `log(dnorm(...))` should contain two log-values (in my example). The probability that they belong in class 0 and probability they belong in class 1. This is the point Eric Peterson makes in his second paragraph.

5. Calculate the posterior probabilities

I also compared my results to R library e1071. My probability results do not line up with theirs for **this simple case**, though the classification does. In their `predict.naiveBayes` function, they have something like `log(apriori) + apply(log(sapply(...compute dnorm code here...)), 1, sum)` which returns `log(apriori) + log(1) = log(apriori)` which is an error so their classification is solely based on the a priori probabilities (actually, they use counts not the probabilities).

Anyways, I hope this helps you (and anyone else) see what's under the hood as it was not clear to me either.

```
n=30 ## samples
set.seed(123)
x = c(rnorm(n/2, 10, 2), rnorm(n/2, 0, 2))
y = as.factor(c(rep(0, 20), rep(1, 10)))
y


#library(e1071)
#nb = naiveBayes(x, y, laplace = 0)
#nb

#nb_predictions = predict(nb, x[1], type='raw')
#nb_predictions



library(dplyr)

nbc <- function(x, y){
  df <- as.data.frame(cbind(x,y))
  a_priori <- table(y) #/length(y)

  cond_probs <- df %>% group_by(y) %>% summarise(means = mean(x), var = sd(x))

  print("A Priori Probabilities")
  print(a_priori/sum(a_priori))

  print("conditional probabilities \n")
  print(cond_probs)

  return(list(apriori = a_priori, tables = cond_probs))
}



predict_nbc <- function(model, new_x){
  apriori = as.matrix(model$apriori)
  a = log(apriori/sum(apriori))
  msd = as.matrix(model$tables)[,c(2,3)] ## creates 3 columsn; first is junk
  probs = sapply(new_x, function(v) dnorm(x = v, mean = msd[,1], sd = msd[,2]))
  b = log(probs)
  #L = a + b ## works for 1 new obs
  L = apply(X = b, MARGIN = 2, FUN = function(v) a + v)

  results <- apply(X = L, MARGIN = 2, function(x){
                   sapply(x, function(lp){ 1/sum(exp(x - lp)) }) ## numerically stable
  })
  return(results)
}



fit = nbc(x,y)

fit ## my naive bayes classifier model

myres = predict_nbc(fit, new_x = x[1:4])
myres
```